# Pandas append dataframe without creating new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I have two dataframes that look like this:

```
df1=
   A   B   
1  A1  B1
2  A2  B2
3  A3  B3

df2 = 
   A   C
4  A4  C4
5  A5  C5
```

I would like to append `df2` to `df1`, like so:

```
   A   B   
1  A1  B1
2  A2  B2
3  A3  B3
4  A4  NaN
5  A5  NaN
```

(Note: I've edited the dataframes so that not all the columns in `df1` are necessarily in `df2`)

Whether I use `concat` or `append`, the resulting dataframe I get would have a column called "C" with the first three rows filled with `nan`. I just want to keep the two original columns in `df1`, with the new values appended. Is there a way concatenate the dataframes without having to drop the extra column afterwards?

Comment: Can you edit to show what you want the final dataframe to look like, given the above example?  I'm having a hard time visualizing it.

Comment: Sorry. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can first filter columns for appending by `subset`:

```
print (df2[['A']])
    A
4  A4
5  A5

print (pd.concat([df1, df2[['A']]]))
    A    B
1  A1   B1
2  A2   B2
3  A3   B3
4  A4  NaN
5  A5  NaN

print (df1.append(df2[['A']]))
    A    B
1  A1   B1
2  A2   B2
3  A3   B3
4  A4  NaN
5  A5  NaN
```

---

```
print (df2[['A','B']])
    A   B
4  A4  B4
5  A5  B5

print (pd.concat([df1, df2[['A','B']]]))
    A   B
1  A1  B1
2  A2  B2
3  A3  B3
4  A4  B4
5  A5  B5
```

Or:

```
print (df1.append(df2[['A','B']]))
    A   B
1  A1  B1
2  A2  B2
3  A3  B3
4  A4  B4
5  A5  B5
```

EDIT by comment:

If columns in `df1` and `df2` have different columns, use [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
print (df1)
    A   B  D
1  A1  B1  R
2  A2  B2  T
3  A3  B3  E

print (df2)
    A   B   C
4  A4  B4  C4
5  A5  B5  C5

print (df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns))
Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')

print (pd.concat([df1, df2[df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)]]))
    A   B    D
1  A1  B1    R
2  A2  B2    T
3  A3  B3    E
4  A4  B4  NaN
5  A5  B5  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. That works for the original way I asked the question. What should I do if not all the columns of df1 are in df2?

Comment: Then you get `NaN` in columns which does not match like `(df1.append(df2))`. Do you need append other way?

Comment: The result you got looks perfectly good, but then you would have to do this for every column that's in df1 but not df2.

Comment: If all columns of `df1` are in `df2`, use `print (pd.concat([df1, df2[df1.columns]]))`

Comment: If not, you can find common columns by [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) `print (df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns))`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution is in an obscure corner of [this page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html). Here's the code to use:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],join_axes=[df1.columns])
```